# Cohomology of compact open subgroups of semisimple groups over local fields

Tags: algebraic-groups, group-cohomology, reductive-groups, local-fields

Let $E$ be a local field, $\mathcal{O}$ its ring of integers, $k$ its residue field, and $G$ a split semisimple group over $\mathcal{O}$. Let $K$ be an open subgroup of $G(\mathcal{O})$; more generally, one could consider any compact open subgroup of the group of rational points of a semisimple group over $E$, but I don't need this.

> Assume that the Dynkin type of $G$ is fixed and $V$ is a non-trivial highest weight representation of $G_E$ (assumed to be irreducible). Is there a constant $N(V)$ depending on the weight of $V$ so that $H^1(K, V) = 0$ if  $p = \mathrm{char}(k) > N(V)$, where the cohomology is group cohomology computed with continuous cochains.
> (The main case of interest for me is when $V$ is the adjoint representation.)

If $\mathrm{char}(E) = 0$ then the vanishing always holds (in all degrees) by results of M. Lazard in this
[paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1965__26__5_0/); the main point is that Lazard proves that group cohomology (of a finite dimensional representation) is almost the same as Lie algebra cohomology (in all degrees) for any $p$-adic analytic group, and the vanishing of Lie algebra cohomology for semisimple Lie algebras is well-known.

If $\mathrm{char}(E) = p$ then the connection with Lie algebra cohomology is not clear (to me). However, the Lie algebra cohomology does vanish if $p \gg_V 0$ and I think $\mathrm{Ext}^1(E,V)$---this is the group of extensions in the category of algebraic representations of $G_E$---is also known to vanish if $p \gg_V 0$, suggesting that the question might have a positive answer even in this case.

(The cohomology does not vanish when $V$ is the trivial representation, but the
trivial representation is anomalous even in characteristic $0$ (as regards the higher cohomology) so perhaps this is not a reason to be pessimistic.)

I was not able to find any references that address this question (and I don't know the answer even for $G = \mathrm{SL}_2$), so any references or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.